# SQL Server connecting LIKE with or

Tags: sql-server, compare, connect, sql-like

Is there a way to connect LIKE statements in SQL and pick the closest case for example I have:

```
FROM Report JOIN SortedData ON Report.ProductDecription LIKE  
'%' + '(%' + SortedData .Products + '%' +  SortedData.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%)' + '%'
|'%' + '(%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' +  ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%)' + '%'
|'%' + '(%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + '%' +  ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%)' + '%'
|'%' + '(%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%)' + '%' 
|'%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' +  ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%'
|'%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' +  ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' 
|'%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%' +  ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%'
|'%' + ChemicalsSorted.Products + '%'
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The data types varchar and text are
>   incompatible in the add operator.

is there any way to connect these together with say an | or an or something along them lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand from your "code" what you are trying to do, you would do it like this:

```
ON SomeColumn LIKE '%This%'
OR SomeColumn LIKE '%That%'
OR SomeColumn LIKE '%Other%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to edit your Join like next:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.TID 
WHERE ( yourField like '%aa%' OR yourField like '%bb%')
```

change fields to yours